# Shell Script Error : too many arguments in input line

Tags: bash, shell

There is a file lets say **List.txt** and it contains the information of files which has to be copy from server to machine and then delete.

When shell scripts executes, it reads the List.txt file, store the files names in a variable, copy files from server to machine and then delete the server's files.

if file **List.txt** contains upto 16 file names then it's working fine.

in case of **List.txt** contains more than 16 files it gives error.

*Error : too many arguments in input line*

Any idea on it.

```
#Path of Log file 
logdir="$HOME/log" 

ftp="/usr/bin/ftp" 

IP="192.168.1.199" 

#User ID to login into remote server 
user="tux" 

#Password to login in remote server 
pass="tux" 

#Mention the path where the files will come in the current server 
getlocaldir="/home/local/in" 

#Mention the path where the FILEs are to FTP(get) in the remote server 
getremotedir="/home/remote/out" 


#Mention type of data transfer "asc" or "bin" 
type="asc" 

#date of FTP - Current date 
dd=`date +%d`

# Creating a log file with datestamp 
log="$logdir/wns_ft.log" 
host=`hostname` 
rc=0 
boj=`date`

#current business date
BUSINESS_DATE=$HOME/file/businessdate

#==================
# Get Business Date
#==================
if [ ! -s $BUSINESS_DATE ]
then
   echo -e "Get system date as the business date" >>$log
   BDATE=`date +%y%m%d`
else
   BDATE=`cut -c3-8 $BUSINESS_DATE` 2>>$log
fi
echo -e "Current business date: $BDATE" >>$log

#a text file contains the name of all file which has to be copied 

bingoFileName=List.txt 

dogetftp ()
{
    LOCAL=$1
    REMOTE=$2

    echo "================================================"
    echo "==          Receiving Files From $IP          =="
    echo "================================================"
    exec 4>&1
    ftp -nv >&4 2>&1 |&

    pid2=$!
    print -p open $IP
    print -p user $user $pass
    print -p asc
    print -p lcd $LOCAL
    print -p cd $REMOTE
    print -p pwd
    print -p prompt
    print -p mget $fileNamesListStr
    print -p mdelete $fileNamesListStr $bingoFileName
    print -p bye
    wait $pid2
}



# method to get the bingo file containing plu-files-names to download
dogetbingo ()
{
    LOCAL=$1
    REMOTE=$2

    echo "================================================"
    echo "==       Receiving Bingo file From $IP        =="
    echo "================================================"
    exec 4>&1
    ftp -nv >&4 2>&1 |&

    pid2=$!
    print -p open $IP
    print -p user $user $pass
    print -p asc
    print -p lcd $LOCAL
    print -p cd $REMOTE
    print -p pwd
    print -p prompt
    print -p mget $bingoFileName
    print -p bye
    wait $pid2
}

# Method to read content of bingo file and creates file name string.
doreadBingo () {
    echo "================================================"
    echo "=           Begin Reading Bingo File           =" 
    echo "================================================"
    LOCAL=$1    

    cd $LOCAL
    if test -f $bingoFileName         # Check if the bingo file exists
    then
        while read -r line
        do    
            fileNamesListStr="$fileNamesListStr $line"
        done < $bingoFileName
    fi
    echo "Files to download: $fileNamesListStr "  
    echo "================================================"
    echo "=            End Reading Bingo File            =" 
    echo "================================================"
}

docheckget () {
    LOCAL=$1
    REMOTE=$2

    DNLD_SUCCESS=`grep 'local: PLU' $log`
    echo "SUCCESS: "$DNLD_SUCCESS
    if [ "X$DNLD_SUCCESS" == "X" ]
    then
        NOT_FND_FILE_NAME="PLUNOTFOUND`date +%Y%m%d`.txt"
        touch $LOCAL/$NOT_FND_FILE_NAME
        echo "================================================"
        echo "==       Sending PLUNOTFOUND File to $IP      =="
        echo "================================================"
        exec 4>&1
        ftp -nv >&4 2>&1 |&

        pid2=$!
        print -p open $IP
        print -p user $user $pass
        print -p asc
        print -p lcd $LOCAL
        print -p cd $REMOTE
        print -p pwd
        print -p prompt
        print -p put $NOT_FND_FILE_NAME
        print -p bye
        wait $pid2

        rm $LOCAL/$NOT_FND_FILE_NAME
    fi
}

case $1 in

mget)   
    #cd $localdir
    exec 1>$log 2>&1 

    echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
    echo "               Transfer bingo file                 " 
    echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
    dogetbingo $getlocaldir $getremotedir

    echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
    echo "     Read bingo file for file names to download    " 
    echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
    doreadBingo $getlocaldir

    echo "---------------------------------------------------" 
    echo "                 Begin FTP Session                 " 
    echo "---------------------------------------------------" 

    if [ "X$fileNamesListStr" != "X" ]
    then
        dogetftp $getlocaldir $getremotedir
        docheckget $getlocaldir $getremotedir
    else
        echo "Nothing in Bingo file to download"
    fi

    echo "---------------------------------------------------"
    echo "                  End FTP Session                  "
    echo "---------------------------------------------------" ;;

esac

exit 0
```

Comment: @paxdiablo : added, please take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is a limitation with `mget` within your FTP client (or at the server end, possibly).

Best advice is to actually create one `get` line per file in `$fileNamesListStr` within the `dogetftp()` function.

For example:

```
dogetftp ()
{
    LOCAL=$1
    REMOTE=$2

    echo "================================================"
    echo "==          Receiving Files From $IP          =="
    echo "================================================"
    exec 4>&1
    ftp -nv >&4 2>&1 |&

    pid2=$!
    print -p open $IP
    print -p user $user $pass
    print -p asc
    print -p lcd $LOCAL
    print -p cd $REMOTE
    print -p pwd
    print -p prompt

    ### Begin change here.
    for fspec in $fileNamesListStr ; do
        print -p get $fspec
        print -p delete $fspec
    done
    print -p delete $bingoFileName
    ### End change here.

    print -p bye
    wait $pid2
}
```

Comment: Yes, it may be possible while i am not so sure about the limitation. Thank you so much. let me try this way. thanks a ton.

Comment: successful. Thank you, Thank you so much.